# Using current divider to see how much current goes inside the plane when lightning strike

Tags: ac, dc, analysis, lightning, current-divider

I am working on a project that requires me to understand how engineers do current analysis. The aircraft has a metallic body which provides a path for lightning when it strikes but what if there is an object hanging outside the plane, how do they determine the amount of current flowing inside the plane. Lets say that certain amount of current has latched onto the cable of the object and flows inside the plane.

The only method I can think of is current divider. 
What other method can help determine that current flowing inside the plane. 
I hope it's not that complicated.

Comment: msgnetic fields may induce currents around a lightning rod.

Comment: There are two current path: through the body of plane, and the cable attached to the object. I am asking for a was to do analysis on how much current goes inside the plane.